# Is “engineering” site suitable place for topics around cyber physical systems and Industry 4.0?

Tags: discussion

Sorry that I do not use meta, not enough reputation.

Although the term "Industry 4.0" might be not the proper one as it sometimes seems to be quite overused for marketing purposes, still I consider matter of fact that the development of the post-industrial society takes the new cycle, which many consider to be the fourth industrial revolution.

Now my question: Is engineering the proper topic to discuss interdisciplinary questions regarding aspects of cyber-physical systems, or what is your opinion if this should be a new Stack Exchange on its own?

Comment: thank you Anonymous for migrating this.

Comment: Wasn't Anonymous who handled the migration, but rather one of your local, friendly site moderators.

Answer (score 4):

Specific, answerable questions related to engineering are on-topic here.  Inter-disciplinary aspects are perfectly fine as well.  This is a site for Engineering, not just XYZ branch of Engineering.

Broad, discussion based questions simply don't work well within the StackExchange Q&A format.  Nebulous questions about fields that are still being defined don't do well within the SE Q&A model.

The guiding principle is to focus on specific issues within a particular problem, and generating content with a high signal to noise ratio.

Based upon your limited description of the topics you're interested in, I would venture that they will not fare well here on Engineering nor on the rest of SE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not ultra active member but I would say:

- CPS development/engineering questions = ok
- CPS other questions (ethics, future prospects,...) = not really

So if you want to discuss CPS in all aspects, you would need a new Stack Exchange. But as I see how smaller SE are having troubles to keep a good content, and lively questions/answers, I would not really suggest it.